# data grid view no affected rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datagridview

I want to fill datagridview when rows affected=< 0 but i get error in line 47 gridview (id) = "correctgridview" runat = "server"
the first case work well but the error in the datagridview

mycode

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
            protected void insertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int rowsaffected = 0;
                dataset ds = new dataset(); 
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; DataBase=attend; Integrated Security=true;");
                SqlCommand cmd;
                cn.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("atten", cn);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
                param.ParameterName = "@myid";
                param.Value = idTextBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                rowsaffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (rowsaffected > 0)
                {
                    resultLabel.Text = "added successful";
                }
                else
                {
                    resultLabel.Text = "attend error";
                    SqlCommand command;
                    command = new SqlCommand("select id, courses.course , course_date , st_lec , location from courses inner join regestration on courses.course = regestration.course where id = 2", cn);
                    SqlDataAdapter adapte = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                    DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
                    adapte.Fill(Dt);
                    correctGridView.DataSource = Dt;
                    correctGridView.DataBind();

                }

                cn.Close();
               }

            }
```

Comment: What error and on which line?

Comment: no underlined for errors but gives me server error when run i think it because the code of datagridview

Comment: It is not clear that what is the error and on which line..

Comment: just I want to fill the datagridview after the condition of else

Comment: Edit your code in the question with some comments which show the line on which the exception is thrown. And give the details of the exception.

Comment: the error: Line 45:     
Line 46:     </div>
Line 47:     <asp:GridView ID="correctGridView" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
Line 48:         ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="260px" 
Line 49:         onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="703px">